# Reading top level domain cookie from subdomain, how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My vbulletin forum sets up some cookies on top level domain `domain-name.com`
I have rails app on `beta.domain-name.com`. Is it possible to read these top level cookies within my app? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, It is possible.

You need to specify domain attribute as `:domain => .domain-name.com`

For example:

```
cookies[:your_cookie] = {:value => 'something', :domain => '.domain-name.com'}
```

Now, cookies can be accessed in `*.domain-name.com` and `domain-name.com`.

Comment: Great, but how can I read it when it was set outside rails app? (in this case by vbulletin forum)